# Solzhenitsyn's Red Wheel

Tags: russian-language, translation, aleksandr-solzhenitsyn

I've heard that all of Solzhenitsyn's work is to be in English by the centennial of his birth, which is this year. I'm trying to understand just what new English translations we can expect this year, especially in the Red Wheel series.

Is the bibliography of Solzhenitsyn's [The Red Wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Red_Wheel) at Wikipedia full and complete? The reason I ask is that the paragraph following the fourth book says that Solzhenitsyn originally intended to carry the cycle through until 1922 when Lenin had his first stroke and went on medical leave. Did any of the books that followed April 1917 ever get written or is April 1917 the absolute end of the cycle?

Has an English translation of April 1917 appeared yet? If not, when can we expect it? Have Russian editions of any further books in the Red Wheel cycle appeared? If so, when can we expect those to appear in English?